# Facebook Connect Dialog Doesn't Auto Close

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have implemented Facebook Connect into a HTML page exactly as the tutorial explains here

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Trying_Out_Facebook_Connect

However when after a user has logged in using the Facebook Dialog, the dialog doesn't close, just shows my webpage in the dialog box?

Has any experienced the same problem and knows what I am missing??

Comment: Are you sure that this question relates to php??? I've found it by tag "php"...

Comment: haha yeah sorry have been using the php library as well, have removed this tag now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your xd_receiver.html file present and in the right place, as specified in the FB.init call? I think I remember having weird problems like this when I had the relative URL to the xd_receiver.html file wrong, and so it wasn't being found by the browser.

Comment: legend, spot on, used an absolute path, which sorted it straight away!